# ffmpeg - reduce background audio noise when recording desktop screen with gdigrab

Tags: ffmpeg

I have an application that records desktop screen using FFmpeg. Here is the command I use

```
ffmpeg.exe -threads 4 -rtbufsize 2048m -f dshow -i audio="Microphone (Realtek Audio)"  -f gdigrab -offset_x 1 -offset_y 1 -video_size 768x432 -probesize 4096M -i desktop -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -crf 28 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -movflags +faststart -r 15 recording.mp4
```

It works fine. But I want to reduce the background noise from the audio. I have found some native filters for this

- [afftdn](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#afftdn)
- [anlmdn](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#anlmdn)
- [arnndn](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#arnndn)

But not sure how to use them while recording screen. Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `-af` (or `-filter_complex`) option with the desired filter name:

```
ffmpeg.exe -threads 4 -rtbufsize 2048m -f dshow -i audio="Microphone (Realtek Audio)" -f gdigrab -offset_x 1 -offset_y 1 -video_size 768x432 -framerate 15 -probesize 4096M -i desktop -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -crf 28 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -af afftdn -movflags +faststart recording.mp4
```

Unrelated change: I removed `-r 15` output option and set the frame rate using the gdigrab `-framerate` option to avoid the unnecessary 25 fps (gdigrab default) to 15 fps conversion

Comment: Thanks @llogan, it works. But there is no noise background reduction. Do you have any idea? `anlmdn` & `afftdn` make no change at all. `arnndn` works with model and reduces noise but that reduce voice quality too

Comment: @Riz I've never used those filters. Only advice I can give is to refer to the documentation for each filter and experiment with all of the options.

Comment: The best noise cancellation filter that works for me is **arnndn** which can be used like `-af  "arnndn=m=filter.rnnn"` where *filter.rnnn* is a physical model file. We can find different noise model files here https://github.com/GregorR/rnnoise-models